# Is it possible to add to a task the time of day for the start and finish of that task?

Tags: 2007

I'd like to add the time a task starts and ends so that it will make the calendar more functional. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please elaborate on your question so that we can give you an accurate answer. For example: Are you attempting something via code? What specifically in the interface are you trying to modify? Are you using a task list or a calendar list?

Comment: Also, please remember to [tag your questions properly](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-i-use-tags-appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into the List Settings and click on the the Start Date (or Due Date) column link. Then, under Date and Time Format, you can change Date only to Date and Time.